# Как вырезать фигуры в LibGdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, рисование

Я пишу приложение под андроид, в котором мне приходится программно рисовать планеты. Сперва я рисую сложную квадратную текстуру, после чего просто вырезаю из нее круг, так я создаю эти планеты на Canvas.

Но теперь я переношу приложение на LibGdx, в котором у меня очень мало опыта. Я отрисовал на Pixmap сложную квадратную текстуру, но не понимаю. как вырезать круг из нее. Как сделать это?

Comment: А сразу нарисовать круг, fillCircle?

Comment: Но тогда круг будет однотонным, а моя текстура должна состоять из фигур различного цвета